# Write very large array to file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, large-files

I've got a client with a Magento shop. They are creating a txt file to upload to googlebase, which contains all of their products, but due to the quantity of products (20k), the script bombs out once it's taken up about 1gb. It's being run via cron.

Is there a way to either zip or segment the array, or write it to the file as it's created, rather than create the array and then write it?

```
<?php
define('SAVE_FEED_LOCATION','/home/public_html/export/googlebase/google_base_feed_cron.txt');



set_time_limit(0);

require_once '/home/public_html/app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app('default');

try{
    $handle = fopen(SAVE_FEED_LOCATION, 'w');


    $heading = array('id','title','description','link','image_link','price','product_type','condition','c:product_code');
    $feed_line=implode("\t", $heading)."\r\n";
    fwrite($handle, $feed_line);

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//enabled
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//catalog, search
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple');//simple only (until fix is made)
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $prodIds=$products->getAllIds();

    foreach($prodIds as $productId) {

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 

        $product->load($productId);

        $product_data = array();
        $product_data['sku']=$product->getSku();
        $product_data['title']=$product->getName();
        $product_data['description']=$product->getShortDescription();
        $product_data['link']=$product->getProductUrl(). '?source=googleps';
        $product_data['image_link']=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();

        // Get price of item
if($product->getSpecialPrice())
            $product_data['price']=$product->getSpecialPrice();
        else
   $product_data['price']=$product->getPrice();


        $product_data['product_type']='';
        $product_data['condition']='new';
        $product_data['c:product_code']=$product_data['sku'];


        foreach($product->getCategoryIds() as $_categoryId){
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId);
            $product_data['product_type'].=$category->getName().', ';
        }
        $product_data['product_type']=rtrim($product_data['product_type'],', ');



        //sanitize data
        foreach($product_data as $k=>$val){
        $bad=array('"',"\r\n","\n","\r","\t");
        $good=array(""," "," "," ","");
        $product_data[$k] = '"'.str_replace($bad,$good,$val).'"';
        }


        $feed_line = implode("\t", $product_data)."\r\n";
        fwrite($handle, $feed_line);
        fflush($handle);
    }

    //---------------------- WRITE THE FEED
    fclose($handle);

}
catch(Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

?>

Comment: Where exactly does it break and with what error message? Every product gets written into the file immediately, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Good point! How much has it written at the time of the crash? Could the problem be in loading the data rather than writing it?

Comment: Free disk space, user quota, PHP version, etc. ? I suspect memory leak in the model. Try PHP 5.3 if you can't clear out the circular references.

Comment: I'd second this. I suspect memory runs out while loading all these objects rather than writing a large string to file. Try logging/echoing memory_get_usage(true) before and after loading specific objects eg $product to see how much memory that takes. Then see if you can't unset() those after they're done, before the next loop iteration. However you might run into circular references with other objects like Rob writes above, where the unset() will not free the memory.

Comment: It looks like it might be a reading issue: /home/public_html/export/googlebase/googlebase.php


Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 71 bytes) in
/home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav
/Mysql4/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php on line 99

Comment: @Jeepstone The location of the error for exhausted memory errors in PHP are usually misleading because it says where memory was last [unsuccessfully] allocated but not where the real memory hog/leak is.

Answer (score 0):

I have two fast answers here:

1) Try to increase php's allowed maximum memory size (for the command line since it is a cron script)

2) The way the senior developers solve similar issues, where I currently work is something like the following:

Create a date field attribute with a name like googlebase_uploaded, and run the cron script with something like const MAX_PRODUCTS_TO_WRITE. 
Then append to the file and flag each product that got appended.

What I am trying to say is slice the execution time into slower chunks that won't break the script.

Unfortunately that's where I'm missing java and c#